# Manually deleting a pointer returned by function

Tags: c++, return-value, nullptr

Let's say i have this code.

```
int* Func(std::vector<int> integers)
{
   for (int i : integers)
   {
       if (something) 
       {
           return &i;
       }
   }

   return nullptr;
}

int* x = Func({3, 4, 5, 6, 7});
delete(x); ???
```

Should i delete 'x'(if it's not nullptr)? As far as i know we should only release memory allocated with the operator 'new'. This is certainly not the case here.

Comment: You are returning a pointer to a local variable. This is undefined behaviour anyway, whether you delete or not. In general, you should not have functions returning raw pointers that the caller might have to delete.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: You are right that you shouldn't `delete`, but that's the least of your worries…

You are returning the address of a local variable (`i`). That's bad karma.

You could try to fix this as follows (note the two extra `&`s):

```
int * Func(std::vector<int> & integers) {
    for (int & i : integers)
        if (something)
            return &i;
    return nullptr;
}
```

But even then you have a problem, since the vector you're passing in is a temporary (`{3, 4, …}`) that gets destroyed before you go past the semicolon. In fact, I don't think it'll even compile, since we're now trying to pass a temporary as an l-value reference.

Since you're using C++11, here's what I think you're trying to accomplish:

```
std::vector<int> integers = {3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
auto x = std::find_if(begin(integers), end(integers), [](int i) { return something; });
if (x != end(integers)) {
    // Use *x…
} else {
    // Not found
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that it should not be `delete`d since it wasn't `new`ed but the biggest problem in your code snippet is that you are returning a pointer to the local variable `i`. This will mean that the pointer returned will have no defined meaning.

Comment: What do you mean? if the condition in Func() is (i == 5) and then i have int* x = Func(...), 'x' will be 5. Note that i'm using gcc.

Comment: `for (int i : integers)` creates the local variable `i` which may well be 5 but when you return from `Func` it goes out of scope so the memory it was stored in is no longer reserved for it so something else could overwrite it before you read it.